# Get list from mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest

I am totally new in javascript. I want to get list of object from mongodb and show them in the table.
This is my code:

**OrderResource**

```
@Path("order/{size}")
@GET
public Object showOrder(@PathParam("size") String size){
    List<DBObject> OrderList = null;
    DBCollection collection = datastore.getDB().getCollection("Order");
    DBCursor OrderCursor = collection.find(QueryBuilder.start("size").is(size).get());
    OrderList = OrderCursor.toArray();

    if (OrderCursor == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }

    GenericEntity<List<DBObject>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<DBObject>>(OrderList) {};
    return Response.ok(entity).build();
}
```

**order.js**

```
coffeeApp.factory('OrderFinder', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/service/coffeeshop/order/:size',
    {size: '@size'}, {}
)});
coffeeApp.controller('FindOrderController', function ($scope, $window, OrderFinder) {
$scope.findOrderBySize = function () {
        OrderFinder.query({size: "medium"}).$promise
            .then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.orders = response.orderBySize;

            });
};
$scope.findOrderBySize();});
```

**order.html**

```
<div ng-controller="FindOrderController" class="container">
<table>
    <tr>

        <th>Drinker</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="OrderBySize in orders">
        <th>{{OrderBySize.drinker}}</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But my table is still empty. What is wrong?

Comment: The most likely answer is that there is no actual data. What did you debug so far? Did you at least add lots of logging to see what data is available on the server side and what the client side receives? System.out.println() / console.log statements, etc. ? The network logging features of your browser can also help a lot to see what is sent and what is received.

Comment: My response contains 18 elements but then something goes wrong. Thanks for the advice, I am trying to find what the problem is.